# How to get the values of comma delimited string into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, split

I have a string `@str =11,22` in a variable. how can I insert this into a table like,

```
 id      num
-------------
 1       11
 2       22
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

Comment: `INSERT INTO tableName (NUM) VALUES (11),(22)` assuming ID is identity [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29b02/1/0) So.. what's the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Comment: You might find [this](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) article helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to get what you're looking for although it is dependent on the values being split by a comma and having no spaces (although you can use trim if you believe this could happen):

```
Declare @str varchar(10) = '11,22,33'
Declare @foobar table (id int identity (1,1), num int)

while (CHARINDEX(',', @str) > 0)
begin
insert into @foobar (num)
Select Left(@Str, CHARINDEX(',', @str) - 1)
Set @str = (select SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX(',', @str) + 1, Len(@str)))
end
if Len(@Str) > 0
    insert into @foobar (num) 
    select @str

select * from @foobar
```

And here is the SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e240/2/0